# After Effects online/Cloud rendering

Tags: render, after-effects

Does any company offer an online rendering service for After Effects?

I have a file with 144 HD clips all masked, and my poor little macbook can't handle it (288 hours render time).

There are no effects, only masks, as it is, in effect, a pre-render.

If anyone has suggestions of how I can speed up this render, would be super appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None that I know of.  You can set up After Effects to render over a local network, of course you'll need multiple computers with After Effects installed.  See here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AfterEffects/9.0/WS3878526689cb91655866c1103a4f2dff7-79a2a.html

There is a company that will be distributing extra CPU cycles but they are not operational yet.  [http://cpusage.com](http://cpusage.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Here's catalog of render form services wiht special topic about After Effects online  http://rentrender.com/after-effects-render-farms/ and Cloud rendering http://rentrender.com/cloud-render-farms-list/ Look and choose what you want and make rendering of your clips